# Moving data from a dict into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I've done a lot of research on this topic and I know there are posts discussing the transfer of data from a Dictionary to a DataFrame but none that address my dilemma.

Basically, I've parsed data out of an HTML table and have stored it in a dictionary. Now I need to move it into a DataFrame so that I can then export it all into an Oracle table. The bad part is that my dictionary only has one Key and all the data is Values.......so when I create a DataFrame with that data, it makes 1 column and 75 rows.

I need to know HOW to put specific data into specific columns, if possible. Does Python or Pandas know the difference between integers and characters and which columns to put them into? Because this code has to work for many different tables of parsed data.

[image: Here's the data table I originally parsed] I only acquire the most recent date's data, so all the data corresponding to 5/20.

Here is my data after being parsed, as a dictionary:

`{'row_of_data': ['ID', 'Available Quota', 'Live Weight Pounds', 'Price', 'Date Posted', '1724', 'GOM COD', 'GOM HADD', 'GOM BB', 'GREYSOLE', 'DABS', 'GOM YT', '2328', '445', '3007', '850', '3101', '1995', 'Package', '$9,000', '5/20', '1578', 'GBE COD', 'GBW COD', 'GB BB', 'GB YT', 'SNE BB', 'SNE YT', 'GOM BB', 'Whake', 'POLL', 'RED', '538', '5894', '1755', '243', '490', '153', '3965', '2727', '9227', '15060', '$1.00', '$0.40', '$0.20', '$1.00', '$0.45', '$0.50', '$0.15', '$0.20', '$0.01', '$0.01', '5/20', '310', 'GBE COD', 'GBW COD', 'DABS', 'WHAKE', 'POLL', 'RED', 'SNE BB', 'GOM BB', '825', '9033', '1241', '3120', '65234', '76610', '1688', '1195', '2121', '7285', 'Package', '$15,000', '5/20']}`

And lastly, here is my attempt at putting the data into a DataFrame:

```
                     0
0                   ID
1      Available Quota
2   Live Weight Pounds
3                Price
4          Date Posted
5                 1724
6              GOM COD
7             GOM HADD
8               GOM BB
9             GREYSOLE
10                DABS
11              GOM YT
12                2328
13                 445
14                3007
15                 850
16                3101
17                1995
18             Package
19              $9,000
20                5/20
21                1578
22             GBE COD
23             GBW COD
24               GB BB
25               GB YT
26              SNE BB
27              SNE YT
28              GOM BB
29               Whake
..                 ...
45               $1.00
46               $0.45
47               $0.50
48               $0.15
49               $0.20
50               $0.01
51               $0.01
52                5/20
53                 310
54             GBE COD
55             GBW COD
56                DABS
57               WHAKE
58                POLL
59                 RED
60              SNE BB
61              GOM BB
62                 825
63                9033
64                1241
65                3120
66               65234
67               76610
68                1688
69                1195
70                2121
71                7285
72             Package
73             $15,000
74                5/20

[75 rows x 1 columns]
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

I would ideally like the printout to be a clean DataFrame, similar to the original data table.

Here is my relevant code:

```
for s in var2:
    if s == str1:
        var4 = {'row_of_data' : [] }
        for idx, val in enumerate(s):
            var4['row_of_data'].extend(rows[idx].stripped_strings)

fish = np.array(values)
print(fish)

fishdf = pd.DataFrame(fish)
print(fishdf)
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>FW: NEFS 2 Available Quota 5/21</title>
<link rel="important stylesheet" href="">
<style>div.headerdisplayname {font-weight:bold;}</style></head>
<body>
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" class="header-part1"><tr><td><b>Subject: </b>FW: NEFS 2 Available Quota 5/21</td></tr><tr><td><b>From: </b>Claire Fitz-Gerald <claire@capecodfishermen.org></td></tr><tr><td><b>Date: </b>5/21/2014 10:08 AM</td></tr></table><br>
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; "><meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 12 (filtered medium)"><!--[if !mso]><style>v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style><![endif]--><style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book";
    panose-1:2 11 5 3 2 1 2 2 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi";
    panose-1:2 11 7 3 2 1 2 2 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
span.EmailStyle17
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:windowtext;}
span.title1
    {mso-style-name:title1;
    font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
    color:#1F487E;
    font-weight:normal;}
span.EmailStyle19
    {mso-style-type:personal-reply;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#1F497D;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-size:10.0pt;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang=EN-US link=blue vlink=purple><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'>Please see the below quota listings.<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'>Thanks,<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'>Claire Fitz-Gerald<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal><i><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></i></p><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-family:"Franklin Gothic Demi","sans-serif";color:#002776'>Cape Cod Commercial Fishermen's Alliance<o:p></o:p></span></b></p><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-family:"Franklin Gothic Book","sans-serif";color:#DE3500'>~ Small Boats.&nbsp; Big Ideas. ~</span></b><b><span style='color:#DE3500'><o:p></o:p></span></b></p></div><p class=MsoNormal><span style='color:#1F497D'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><div><div style='border:none;border-top:solid #B5C4DF 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 0in 0in 0in'><p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'>From:</span></b><span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"'> David Leveille [mailto:nefs02@gmail.com] <br><b>Sent:</b> Wednesday, May 21, 2014 8:50 AM<br><b>To:</b> David Leveille<br><b>Subject:</b> NEFS 2 Available Quota 5/21<o:p></o:p></span></p></div></div><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:#1F487E'>AVAILABLE QUOTA FY 2014</span><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'><o:p></o:p></span></p><table class=MsoNormalTable border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="71%" style='width:71.28%'><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>ID <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Available Quota <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Live Weight Pounds <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Price <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:#8BCDFF;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='mso-line-height-alt:15.0pt'><b><span style='font-size:18.0pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Date Posted <o:p></o:p></span></b></p></td></tr><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1724<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM COD<br>GOM HADD<br>GOM BB<br>GREYSOLE<br>DABS<br>GOM YT<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>2328<br>445<br>3007<br>850<br>3101<br>1995<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Package<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$9,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/20<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1578<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GBE COD<br>GBW COD<br>GB BB<br>GB YT<br>SNE BB<br>SNE YT<br>GOM BB<br>Whake<br>POLL<br>RED<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>538<br>5894<br>1755<br>243<br>490<br>153<br>3965<br>2727<br>9227<br>15060<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$1.00<br>$0.40<br>$0.20<br>$1.00<br>$0.45<br>$0.50<br>$0.15<br>$0.20<br>$0.01<br>$0.01<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/20<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>310<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GBE COD<br>GBW COD<br>DABS<br>WHAKE<br>POLL<br>RED<br>SNE BB<br>GOM BB<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>825<br>9033<br>1241<br>3120<br>65234<br>76610<br>1688<br>1195<br>2121<br>7285<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Package<o:p></o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$15,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/20<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr style='height:23.25pt'><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>347<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>SNE BB<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>8,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$0.50<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt;height:23.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/7<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1878A<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GOM COD<br>GOM HADD<br>SNE BB<br>GOM BB<br>GB BB<br>GREYSOLE<br>GOM YT<br>SNE YT<br>POLL<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>6188<br>635<br>3916<br>7873<br>6762<br>3358<br>9776<br>271<br>186550<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>$1.95<br>$1.35<br>$0.50<br>$0.50<br>$0.20<br>$1.40<br>$1.20<br>$0.50<br>$0.01<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/12<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr><tr><td width=220 style='width:164.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1878B<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=161 style='width:120.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>GBE COD<br>GBW COD<br>GB YT<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=189 style='width:141.75pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>1113<br>12186<br>850<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=126 style='width:94.55pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>Package<br>$10,000<o:p></o:p></span></p></td><td width=168 style='width:125.95pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;background:white;padding:2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt 2.25pt'><p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:15.0pt'><span style='font-size:13.5pt;font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";color:black'>5/12<o:p></o:p></span></p></td></tr></table><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>David Leveille<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>II Northeast Fishery Sector Inc.<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>10 Witham Street<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Gloucester, MA. 01930<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Cell 978 375 3509<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Fax 978 281 1555<o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal>Web <a href="http://nefs2.com/">http://nefs2.com/</a><o:p></o:p></p><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p><div class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align:center'><span style='font-size:12.0pt;font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'></body></html>
</body>
</html>
```

New code being used:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
import lxml
import html5lib

path = 'C:\\EVERYTHING FROM Z DRIVE\\blub'

def readhtml(path):
    df = pd.pandas.read_html(io =path)
    print(df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    readhtml('path')
```

Comment: Have you tried to read them using pandas.read_html   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html#pandas-read-html   . Also this has option to specify the data types for each column using converters

Comment: Hmmm I didn't even know you could read in a table from Pandas. The thing with this project is though that I am going to need code that is powerful enough to parse tons of different HTML tables. So my code right now captures the top right date, sees "if" that date occurs again then capture all corresponding data....can this pandas.read_html do something like that?

Comment: Yes , read the html table into Pandas first and then you can do all kind of filters in dataframe

Comment: can you upload a few __sample__ HTML pages and post here corresponding links?

Comment: Why does the dictionary have to have one column? Could that part of the process be changed?

Comment: @pshep123 do you mean the DataFrame? I don't want the DataFrame to be one column, that's just how it prints and I don't know why... I want the DataFrame to basically look like the original data table

Comment: No, I mean the dictionary.  You gloss over the "parse from HTML to dictionary" part.  I imagine there's a way to parse the HTML into a dictionary format that simply requires you to write a single line of code to put it to a DataFrame.

Comment: Ohh I see where you're confused. Umm so basically I asked for help on how to parse an HTML table and the help I received said to create an empty dictionary and then append the data into it, which worked for the most part. But now when I go to turn that dictionary into a DataFrame via `df = pd.DataFrame(fish)` it enters all the data into a single column, probably because it's all values with only one key?

Answer (score 0):

```
def readhtml(path):
    df=pd.pandas.read_html(io =path)
    print df


if __name__=="__main__":
    readhtml('C:\Users\xxx\samples.html')
```

Below is sample of html used for testing

Output created by this program is

```
[      0    1    2    3
0    ID   H1   H2   H3
1     1   X1   Y1   Y2
2   NaN   X2   Y1   Y2
3   NaN   X3   Y1   Y2
4   NaN   X4   Y1   Y2
5     2   X5   Y1   Y2
6   NaN   X6   Y1   Y2
7   NaN   X7   Y1   Y2
8   NaN   X8   Y1   Y2
9   NaN   X9   Y1   Y2
10  NaN  X10   Y1   Y2
11    2  X11   Y1   Y2
12  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN]
```

```html
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Excel 14">
<link rel=File-List href="samples_files/filelist.xml">
<style id="sample_14456_Styles">
<!--table
 {mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";
 mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\,";}
.xl1514456
 {padding-top:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 padding-left:1px;
 mso-ignore:padding;
 color:black;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
 mso-font-charset:0;
 mso-number-format:General;
 text-align:general;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 mso-background-source:auto;
 mso-pattern:auto;
 white-space:nowrap;}
.xl6514456
 {padding-top:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 padding-left:1px;
 mso-ignore:padding;
 color:#3E4349;
 font-size:9.0pt;
 font-weight:700;
 font-style:normal;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
 mso-font-charset:0;
 mso-number-format:General;
 text-align:general;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 mso-background-source:auto;
 mso-pattern:auto;
 white-space:nowrap;}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<!--[if !excel]>&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->
<!--The following information was generated by Microsoft Excel's Publish as Web
Page wizard.-->
<!--If the same item is republished from Excel, all information between the DIV
tags will be replaced.-->
<!----------------------------->
<!--START OF OUTPUT FROM EXCEL PUBLISH AS WEB PAGE WIZARD -->
<!----------------------------->

<div id="sample_14456" align=center x:publishsource="Excel">

<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=256 style='border-collapse:
 collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:192pt'>
 <col width=64 span=4 style='width:48pt'>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl6514456 width=64 style='height:14.4pt;width:48pt'>ID</td>
  <td class=xl1514456 width=64 style='width:48pt'>H1</td>
  <td class=xl1514456 width=64 style='width:48pt'>H2</td>
  <td class=xl1514456 width=64 style='width:48pt'>H3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl1514456 align=right style='height:14.4pt'>1</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>X1</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y1</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl1514456 style='height:14.4pt'></td>
  <td class=xl1514456>X2</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y1</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl1514456 style='height:14.4pt'></td>
  <td class=xl1514456>X3</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y1</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl1514456 style='height:14.4pt'></td>
  <td class=xl1514456>X4</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y1</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl1514456 align=right style='height:14.4pt'>2</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>X5</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y1</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl1514456 style='height:14.4pt'></td>
  <td class=xl1514456>X6</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y1</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl1514456 style='height:14.4pt'></td>
  <td class=xl1514456>X7</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y1</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl1514456 style='height:14.4pt'></td>
  <td class=xl1514456>X8</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y1</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl1514456 style='height:14.4pt'></td>
  <td class=xl1514456>X9</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y1</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl1514456 style='height:14.4pt'></td>
  <td class=xl1514456>X10</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y1</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=19 style='height:14.4pt'>
  <td height=19 class=xl1514456 align=right style='height:14.4pt'>2</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>X11</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y1</td>
  <td class=xl1514456>Y2</td>
 </tr>
 <![if supportMisalignedColumns]>
 <tr height=0 style='display:none'>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
 </tr>
 <![endif]>
</table>

</div>


<!----------------------------->
<!--END OF OUTPUT FROM EXCEL PUBLISH AS WEB PAGE WIZARD-->
<!----------------------------->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried that and got the error `lxml not found, please install it`

Comment: Ok, you need to install lxml library

Comment: Lol I've honestly been struggling to install this lxml library for an hour now. Usually I can just download it and then do the simple pip install in the command window but it hasn't been working so hold tight

Comment: if you are not able to install using PIP , download source code  from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.7.0. now you can install it by following command 'python setup.py install'   
  
 1 Download and extract the .zip / .tar.gz package

   2 From command line change to that directory. Directory should contain setup.py  file among other things.

   3 From command line run

Comment: Idk why but it says that setup.py is `no such file or directory` and it fails. Sorry for being such a noob I really am trying to figure this out. I've tried downloading a few different lxml files and none work. Some installations appear to work for a few seconds and then fail, for a plethora of reasons. And neither `pip install` nor `easy_install` seem to work. It's really frustrating that these simple installations of modules always take me a really long time

Comment: just follow the above steps and you should be able to install it without any issues !!!!

Comment: Ok. So I installed `lxml` and also `html5lib` because it was required too. Now when I run the program you outlined above I get `ValueError: no tables found`. Googling that error unfortunately did not reveal much. Maybe it's struggling to create the DataFrame from the data? Any suggestions?

Comment: I am able to run the same script with HTML from you without any issue. Also can you please edit your question with latest code that you have?

Comment: I added in the code I'm currently using. The line that is causing the error is the: `df = pd.pandas.read_html(io =path)` line